# How to indent nested if/for statements in jinja2

Tags: nested, ansible, jinja2, indentation

I have a long Jinja2 template which has many nested `if`/`for` statements. It's very hard to read. I would like to indent the `{% %}` bits, to make it clearer.
However if I do that, the contents of those blocks gets indented further too.

How can I indent *just* the `{% %}` bits?

I'm using Ansible.

## Steps to reproduce:

`template.yaml.j2`

```
{% for x in range(3) %}
Key{{ x }}:
   # The following should be one list
   - always here
   {% if x % 2 %}
   - sometimes here
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

`playbook.yaml`

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  tasks:
    - template:
        src: template.j2
        dest: template.yaml
```

Run with `ansible-playbook playbook.yaml`

## Desired Output

```
Key0:
   # The following should be one list
   - always here
Key1:
   # The following should be one list
   - always here
   - sometimes here
Key2:
   # The following should be one list
   - always here
```

## Actual behavior:

```
Key0:
   # The following should be one list
   - always here
   Key1:
   # The following should be one list
   - always here
      - sometimes here
   Key2:
   # The following should be one list
   - always here
```

## Workaround

If I unindent the `if` statements like:

```
{% for x in range(3) %}
Key{{ x }}:
   # The following should be one list
   - always here
{% if x % 2 %}
   - sometimes here
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Then I get the output I want.
But the problem is that this is hard to read. (In my actual template, I have if statements inside for inside if, etc. Highly nested.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Q: ***"How to indent nested if/for statements in Jinja2?"***

A: Turn off default trimming and manually *ltrim* only indented control statements *`{%-`*. For example, the template below does what you're looking for

```yaml
shell> cat templates/template.j2
#jinja2: trim_blocks: False
{% for x in range(3) %}
Key{{ x }}:
   # The following should be one list
   - always here
   {%- if x % 2 %}
   - sometimes here
   {%- endif %}
{%- endfor %}
```

The task

```yaml
    - template:
        src: template.j2
        dest: template.yaml
```

creates the file *template.yaml*

```yaml
shell> cat template.yaml 

Key0:
  # The following should be one list
  - always here
Key1:
  # The following should be one list
  - always here
  - sometimes here
Key2:
  # The following should be one list
  - always here
```

See [Whitespace Control](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#whitespace-control).

---

Notes

1. The dash in *`{%- endfor %}`* removes the empty line among the keys.
2. By default parameter *`trim_blocks: yes`*. See [template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html#template-template-a-file-out-to-a-remote-server).
3. The documentation section [Whitespace Control](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#whitespace-control) says:

> You can manually disable the trim_blocks behavior by putting a plus sign (+) at the end of a block

Then, the following template gives the same result

```yaml
shell> cat templates/template.j2
{% for x in range(3) %}
Key{{ x }}:
  # The following should be one list
  - always here
  {%- if x % 2 +%}
  - sometimes here
  {%- endif +%}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to fight with the manual whitespace control. I ended up adding whitespace in the template tags, like this:

```
{% for x in range(3) %}
Key{{ x }}:
   # The following should be one list
   - always here
{%   if x % 2 %}
   - sometimes here
{%   endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Note the extra space before the `if` and `endif`.